# how to set the file_src for sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable from action in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to set the file src for my `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` from my action class which is

I tried with the following code but is always has the value which I set in Baseform only

```
$this->Form->setOption('file_name',array(
    'file_src' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir')."\\". $dirId ."\\".$this->imgName,
    'is_image' => true, 'edit_mode' => true, 'delete_label' => true, 'with_delete' =>false
));
```

`$dirid` is the folder name. I can get `$dirid` in BaseForm so I want to overwrite the `file_src` from my action class.

Why the above code is not working?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass only one parameter to `setOption()` at a time. Or you can use `setOptions()` to override all options at once.

Do you have `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` in a genrated base form? I don't think so. **Please do NOT edit generated base classes by hand.**

Please read at least [this chapter](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_alternative_ways_to_use_a_form) in the docs.

**NOTE:** Why the company id is required?

I think it should be better to put it into the form like this:

```php
// EditSlideForm.class.php
public function configure()
{
  //...

  // use this if the file is optional
  $this->setWidget('file_name', new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
    'file_src' => $this->getObject()->getPublicFileLocation(),
    'is_image' => true,
    'with_delete' => (boolean) $this->getObject()->getFile(),
    'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew() && $this->getObject()->getFileName(),
  )));
  $this->setValidator('file_name', new sfValidatorFile(array(
    'mime_types' => 'web_images',
    'path' => $this->getObject()->getFileDir(),
    'required' => false,
  )));
  $this->setValidator('file_name_delete', new sfValidatorBoolean());

  // use this if the file is required
  $this->setWidget('file_name', new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
    'file_src' => $this->getObject()->getPublicFileLocation(),
    'is_image' => true,
    'with_delete' => false,
    'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew() && $this->getObject()->getFileName(),
  )));
  $this->setValidator('file_name', new sfValidatorFile(array(
    'mime_types' => 'web_images',
    'path' => $this->getObject()->getFileDir(),
  )));

  //...
}
```

This is how I usally do it. An you should add `getPublicFileLocation()` and `getFileDir()` to the model e.g.:

```php
static public function getFileDir()
{
  return sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/slide-file';
}

public function getPublicFileLocation()
{
  return str_replace(sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir'), '', self::getFileDir()) . '/' . $this->getFileName();
}
```